# Avoid branching in the following statement

Tags: if-statement, compiler-optimization

I got the following computation:

```
if (x==0) x=1.0;
Y = x * A
```

Any idea how can i avoid the "if" branching above by using some math clamping/step functions.

Comment: can you provide some surrounding code? what possible values are there for x?

Comment: Your CPU might be able to use a CMOV* instruction (assuming an Intel/AMD instruction set here, but some other chip families have similar capabilities) to (re-)load `x`, which would avoid a branch, if you want to use inline assembly (or even non-inline assembly). Whether or not your compiler will generate such code depends greatly on the compiler, which version of the compiler, and the options you're giving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Y=((x==0)+(x!=0)*x)*A;
```

icc -O3 compiles this without a jmp (gcc/llvm do not) for x86-64 (checked with https://gcc.godbolt.org).

Comment: Clang and GCC do too, if you compile with -ffast-math (ICC is a bit more loose with that by default it seems)

Comment: I thought about imprecision as well when creating the proposed expression but I cannot see how the posted expression could result in any difference to the initial expression so -ffast-math should make no difference. Do I miss something?

Comment: Yes, but for the gcc code, I cannot see a precision loss or a reason why this code is generated only with fast-math. For the clang code, it is obvious, it uses an fma operation.